# Creating an application pool in iis through bat file

Tags: c#, .net, iis, batch-file

I used the following code to use the inbuild application pool which as asp.net4.0 through bat command as

```
%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD set app "Sample" /applicationPool:"ASP.NET v4.0 Classic"
%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD set apppool /apppool.name:"ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" /managedPipelineMode:Integrated
```

but through this if ASP.NET v4.0 Classic is not present in the iis then it will throws error

so I need to install aspnet_regiis -i and the create a new pool with the pipeline mode :integrated through bat file.

Can you provide me a solution?

Answer (score 6):

i found solution as

to create application pool :

```
%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD add apppool /name:Poolname
```

To add application to pool :

```
%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD set app "applicationname" /applicationPool:"Poolname"
```

to set the other properties of that pool  :

```
%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD set apppool /apppool.name:"Poolname" /managedPipelineMode:Integrated
```

Start the created pool :

```
%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD start apppool /apppool.name:"Poolname"
```

Install aspnet4.0 framework in iis as

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Note: we can use any framework here.....

Comment: unfortunately APPCMD only works for iis7, so you might as wel use the managed api then , which is a lot easier to use ! http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/using-managed-apis-in-iis-7